# How do I parse a BsonDocument using C#

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, bson

I just started learning MongoDb and have no experience with nosql(not only sql) databases so I am sorry if the answer is obvious. There I create a document with two fields. "name" and "id" respectively. Then I put 5 documents into it. Here is my problem. I could not figure out how I list only name names without any field.

```
 internal static class Program
        {
            // connects to db
            private static readonly MongoClient DbClient = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
            // reads database 
            private static readonly IMongoDatabase Db = DbClient.GetDatabase("STAJDB");
            // list of databases 
            static List<BsonDocument> _collList = Db.ListCollections().ToList();
            // documents 
            private static readonly IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> UserList = Db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("users");

            public static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                const string documentName = "users";
                CreateUser("ekko", 1023, documentName);
                CreateUser("ryze", 1437, documentName);
                CreateUser("yasuo", 1234, documentName);
                CreateUser("vayne", 873, documentName);
                CreateUser("teemo", 453, documentName);

                ListAllUsers();
            }

            private static void CreateUser(string name, int id, string documentName)
            {
                var personDoc = new BsonDocument();
                var personFirstNameElement = new BsonElement("name", name);  
                personDoc.Add(personFirstNameElement);  
                personDoc.Add(new BsonElement("id", id));  
                UserList.InsertOne(personDoc); 
            }

            private static void ListAllUsers()
            {
                var result = UserList.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }  
          }
```

The output looks like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4733cfe35d52228c68000b"), "name" : "ekko", "id" : 1023 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4733cfe35d52228c68000c"), "name" : "ryze", "id" : 1437 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4733cfe35d52228c68000d"), "name" : "yasuo", "id" : 1234 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4733cfe35d52228c68000e"), "name" : "vayne", "id" : 873 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b4733cfe35d52228c68000f"), "name" : "teemo", "id" : 453 }
```

How do I extract only the names from this? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a BsonDocument into a strongly typed object with the official MongoDB C# driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24375928/how-to-convert-a-bsondocument-into-a-strongly-typed-object-with-the-official-mon)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I did exactly what the most upvoted answer suggested and get this "ConsoleApplication1.User".

Comment: Don't use `Console.WriteLine(item);`, use something like `Console.WriteLine(item.Name);`